# Dereferencing in C

Tags: c, pointers, c99, c89

I've just started to learn C so please be kind.
From what I've read so far regarding pointers:

```
int * test1; //this is a pointer which is basically an address to the process 
             //memory and usually has the size of 2 bytes (not necessarily, I know)
float test2; //this is an actual value and usually has the size of 4 bytes,
             //being of float type
test2 = 3.0; //this assigns 3 to `test2`
```

Now, what I don't completely understand:

```
*test1 = 3; //does this assign 3 at the address 
            //specified by `pointerValue`?
test1 = 3;  //this says that the pointer is basically pointing 
            //at the 3rd byte in process memory, 
            //which is somehow useless, since anything could be there
&test1; //this I really don't get, 
        //is it the pointer to the pointer? 
        //Meaning, the address at which the pointer address is kept?
        //Is it of any use?
```

Similarly:

```
*test2; //does this has any sense?
&test2; //is this the address at which the 'test2' value is found? 
        //If so, it's a pointer, which means that you can have pointers pointing 
        //both to the heap address space and stack address space. 
        //I ask because I've always been confused by people who speak about 
        //pointers only in the heap context.
```

Comment: A pointer had two bytes in the 70s. Now it's typically eight bytes, as it has to address a 64-bit memory space.

Comment: *test2 means nothing, it probably won't even compile.

Comment: Ah, I get it, but it could have 4 bytes as well right? Since 32-bit memory spaces are pretty common these days as well

Comment: Pointer size is implementation specific, meaning it depends upon the platform that you are compiling to.

Comment: You've got it mostly right.  &test2 returns a pointer to a float.  &test1 returns a pointer to a pointer to an int.  *test2 is invalid, since you can't dereference a float or any other "scalar" value -- only pointers.

Comment: @Dancrumb 's answer answered all your questions. I'd recommend you read this nicely written tutorial to understand pointers better: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

Your first block is correct. A pointer is a variable that holds the address of some data. The type of that pointer tells the code how to interpret the contents of the address being held by that pointer.

The construct:

```
*test1 = 3
```

Is called the deferencing of a pointer. That means, you can access the address that the pointer points to and read and write to it like a normal variable. Note:

```
int *test;
/*
 *    test is a pointer to an int - (int *)
 *   *test behaves like an int - (int)
 *
 * So you can thing of (*test) as a pesudo-variable which has the type 'int' 
 */
```

The above is just a mnemonic device that I use.

It is rare that you ever assign a numeric value to a pointer... maybe if you're developing for a specific environment which has some 'well-known' memory addresses, but at your level, I wouldn't worry to much about that.

Using

```
*test2
```

would ultimately result in an error. You'd be trying to deference something that is not a pointer, so you're likely to get some kind of system error as who knows where it is pointing.

`&test1` and `&test2` are, indeed, pointers to `test1` and `test2`.

Pointers to pointers are very useful and a search of [pointer to a pointer](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8ion=1&#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&gs_rn=0&gs_ri=hp&gs_mss=pointer%20to%20const%20data&tok=E1-x8K21GePY3sU1D6Bxvg&cp=20&gs_id=g&xhr=t&q=pointer+to+a+pointer&pf=p&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=pointer+to+a+pointer&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355272958,d.aWM&fp=f5fe22852b21d77a&bpcl=39942515&biw=1855&bih=968) will lead you to some resources that are way better than I am.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the first part right.

An incidental thought: there are various conventions about where to put that `*` sign. I prefer mine nestled with the variable name, as in `int *test1` while others prefer `int* test1`. I'm not sure how common it is to have it floating in the middle.

Another incidental thought: `test2 = 3.0` assigns a floating-point 3 to `test2`. The same end could be achieved with `test2=3`, in which case the 3 is implicitly converted from an integer to a floating point number. The convention you have chosen is probably safer in terms of clarity, but is not strictly necessary.

Non-incidentals

`*test1=3` does assign 3 to the address specified by `test`.

`test1=3` is a line that has meaning, but which I consider meaningless. We do not know what is at memory location 3, if it is safe to touch it, or even if we are allowed to touch it.

That's why it's handy to use something like

```
int var=3;
int *pointy=&var;
*pointy=4;
//Now var==4.
```

The command `&var` returns the memory location of `var` and stores it in `pointy` so that we can later access it with `*pointy`.

But I could also do something like this:

```
int var[]={1,2,3};
int *pointy=&var;
int *offset=2;
*(pointy+offset)=4;
//Now var[2]==4.
```

And this is where you might legitimately see something like `test1=3`: pointers can be added and subtracted just like numbers, so you can store offsets like this.

`&test1` is a pointer to a pointer, but that sounds kind of confusing to me. It's really the address in memory where the value of `test1` is stored. And `test1` just happens to store as its value the address of another variable. Once you start thinking of pointers in this way (address in memory, value stored there), they become easier to work with... or at least I think so.

I don't know if `*test2` has "meaning", per se. In principle, it could have a use in that we might imagine that the `*` command will take the value of `test2` to be some location in memory, and it will return the value it finds there. But since you define `test2` as a float, it is difficult to predict where in memory we would end up, setting `test2=3` will not move us to the third spot of anything (look up the IEEE754 specification to see why). But I would be surprised if a compiler would allow such thing.

Let's look at another quick example:

```
int var=3;
int pointy1=&var;
int pointy2=&pointy1;
*pointy1=4;  //Now var==4
**pointy2=5; //Now var==5
```

So you see that you can chain pointers together like this, as many in a row as you'd like. This might show up if you had an array of pointers which was filled with the addresses of many structures you'd created from dynamic memory, and those structures contained pointers to dynamically allocated things themselves. When the time comes to use a pointer to a pointer, you'll probably know it. For now, don't worry too much about them.

Answer (score 1):

First let's add some confusion: the word "pointer" can refer to either a variable (or object) with a pointer type, or an *expression* with the pointer type. In most cases, when people talk  about "pointers" they mean pointer variables.

A pointer can (**must**) point to a **thing** (An "object" in standards parlance). It can only point to the **right kind** of thing; a pointer to int is not *supposed* to point to a float object. A pointer can also be NULL; in that case there is no thing to point to.

A pointertype is also a type, and a pointer object is also an object. So it is allowable to construct a pointer to pointer: the pointer-to-pointer just stores the addres of the pointer object.

What a pointer can **not** be:

- It cannot point to a value: `p = &4;` is impossible. 4 is a literal value, which is not stored in an object, and thus has no address.
- the same goes for expressions: `p = &(1+4);` is impossible, because the expression "1+4" does not have a location.
- the same goes for return value `p = &sin(pi);` is impossible; the return value is not an object and thus has no address.
- variables marked as "register" (almost distinct now) cannot have an address.
- you cannot take the address of a bitfield, basically because these can be smaller than character (or have a finer granularity), hence it would be possible that different bitmasks would have the same address.

There are some "exceptions" to the above skeletton (void pointers, casting, pointing one element beyond an array object) but *for clarity* these should be seen as refinements/amendments, IMHO.